# batchwise Sql script to execute in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have SQL script which will generate millions of rows and insert to DB table. How can I execute that script in SSIS in batchwise? Is there any easier solution?

Example:

```
declare @userinput1 int =1
declare @userinput2 int =10000000;


INSERT INTO table2(col1)
SELECT ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1000*thousands.n + 10000*laks.n+100000*laks10.n +1000000*crore.n
FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
     (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
     (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) hundreds(n),
     (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) thousands(n),
     (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) laks(n),
     (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) laks10(n),
     (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) crore(n)
WHERE ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1000*thousands.n + 10000*laks.n +100000* laks10.n +1000000*crore.n  BETWEEN @userinput1 AND @userinput2
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Use a Execute SQL Task? This is very vague here, you need to be more specific on what you're *really* trying to achieve here.

Comment: Thanks.is there any option in ExecuteSQLTask run batchwise?

Comment: @lamu Actually Sql script will generate range of sequence number with other column details  and insert to table ..

Comment: Can you give an example what the sql script you want to execute looks like?

Comment: actually i want to insert genearted values to table..Sometime i am getting memory exception..so i need to execute this to batchwise

Comment: @Ljt please edit the query in your question...

Comment: Still don't reaklly understand what you're asking. Are you saying you want SSIS to only process 1,000 rows at a time?

Comment: i  have updated the question with ex...i need to implement similar in ssis.. Is possible?

Comment: Yes it's absolutely possible. You can pass the user input variables to the execute sql task. I think "Batchwise" is confusing people.. I don't see any such code your question

Comment: Thanks..i havent implemented batch in SQL.is it possible call  execute sql task multiple times based to batch size? is it more efficient?

Comment: Why do you want to loop over it ? is it very slow if you insert all rows at once?

Comment: i heard that batchwise is more effiencnt..so i want replace with batchwsie

Comment: You select the batch size in the data flow tab, under the target operation's properties.

Answer (score 1):

Use a WHILE loop and only insert a batch at a time, starting from `@UserInput1`, until you reach `@UserInput2`.